# How to set margin left and right to center a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
myUserControl = new myUserControl(this);
myUserControl.Margin = new Thickness(300, 0, -300, 0);
mainDockPanel.Children.Add(myUserControl);
DockPanel.SetDock(myUserControl, Dock.Top);
```

I would like to have myUserControl at center of the screen, even when the user maximize the window.
I guess I could do it if the code above worked u.U
Any ideias? Thank you.

Comment: Margins are not the right tool, you will need something with 'center' in the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"` with a fixed Width or a fixed Margin?

You can also wrap it in a stretching control like a Grid, something like:

```
myUserControl = new myUserControl(this);
Grid grid = new Grid();
myUserControl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
myUserControl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
grid.Children.Add(myUserControl);
mainDockPanel.Children.Add(grid);
DockPanel.SetDock(grid, Dock.Top);
```